# Fake Marquee Text in Haskell

Tags: haskell

This is my very first complete, non-completely-trivial Haskell program, and I'm extremely unfamiliar with the language.  I was hoping that I could get some pointers on how to make it more idiomatic.  I'm especially unfamiliar with built-in functions.

I'm specifically concerned with my `main` function and my `scrollHelp` guards, as it feels like there should be a better way to do both.  Also the naming of the `scroll` and `scrollHelp` functions is arbitrary, and they might be able to be combined.

The program itself is very simple, it takes a numerical width and a string as command line parameters and transforms that string into a fake marquee.

Example:

> ./scroll 4 testing

```
[    ]
[   t]
[  te]
[ tes]
[test]
[esti]
[stin]
[ting]
[ing ]
[ng  ]
[g   ]
[    ]
```

scroll.hs

```
import System.Environment
import System.Exit
import System.IO

slice :: Int -> Int -> [Char] -> [Char]
slice from to xs = take to $ drop from $ xs

slice0 :: Int -> [Char] -> [Char]
slice0 = slice 0

join :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [a]
join a xss = concatMap (++ a) xss

spaces :: Int -> [Char]
spaces a = concat $ take a $ repeat " "

lead = "    ["
end = "]"

format :: [Char] -> [Char]
format xs = lead ++ xs ++ end

scroll :: Int -> [Char] -> [[Char]]
scroll a [] = [format $ spaces a]
scroll a x = scrollHelp a (spaces a ++ x ++ spaces a)

scrollHelp :: Int -> [Char] -> [[Char]]
scrollHelp a xall@(_:xs)
  | length xall >= a = (format $ slice0 a xall) : scrollHelp a xs
  | otherwise      = []
scrollHelp a _ = []

main = do
  args <- getArgs
  case args of
    [widthString, text] | [(width,_)] <- reads widthString ->
      putStrLn $ join "\n" (scroll width text)
    _ -> do
      name <- getProgName
      hPutStrLn stderr $ "usage: " ++ name ++ " <marquee width> <text to marquee>"
      exitFailure
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- use `replicate a ' '` instead of `concat $ take a $ repeat " "`
- use pattern matching in main to check that there are exactly two arguments and use it also for read to check that the width is exactly a number. With `[(width,_)]` you accept also strings that only start with a number, such as "1O" where probably you made a mistake and you wrote it instead of "10"
- `lead` and `end` can be specific to format to avoid exposing them. Actually you can also remove them and just write `"    [" ++ xs ++ "]"`
- `scroll` can be simplified and both the helper and the `format` function can should be only visible to it
- don't concat the output together before writing it: just write each line in output. Use`forM_` for multiple `IO` operations over a list of values.

So, my rewrite of your code is

```
import Control.Monad (forM_)
import System.Environment
import System.Exit
import System.IO


scroll :: Int -> [Char] -> [[Char]]
scroll a = reverse . scrollHelp [] . addSpaces
  where
    addSpaces xs = replicate a ' ' ++ xs ++ replicate a ' '
    scrollHelp acc str
      | length str < a = acc
      | otherwise      = let group = take a str
                         in scrollHelp (format group:acc) (tail str)
    format xs = "    [" ++ xs ++ "]"

main = do
  args <- getArgs
  case args of
    (widthString:text:[]) ->
       case reads widthString of
         [(width,"")] -> forM_ (scroll width text) putStrLn 
         _ -> hPutStrLn stderr $ "width must be an integer, got '" ++ widthString ++ "'"
    _ -> do
      name <- getProgName
      hPutStrLn stderr $ "usage: " ++ name ++ " <marquee width> <text to marquee>"
      exitFailure
```